# Beneifts of line continuation in Dockerfiles

Tags: docker

I've been working with Docker recently to host an RStudio-server instance.  There are a number of packages that need to be installed, an one way to do this in a Dockerfile is this (with many more lines, obviously):

```
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('beanplot')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('beeswarm')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('boot')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('caTools')"
```

I see many instances where this is done this way:

```
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages(c('beanplot','beeswarm','boot','caTools'))
```

Also, I often see various executable lines chained together like this:

```
RUN yum -y update \
 && yum -y groupinstall 'Development Tools' \
 && yum -y install epel-release \
                   vim \
                   initscripts \
                   libpng-devel \
                   mesa-libGL \
                   mesa-libGL-devel \
                   mesa-libGLU \
                   mesa-libGLU-devel \
                   ypbind \
                   rpcbind \
                   authconfig \
 && yum -y install R \  
 && mkdir /rhome
```

rather than having is && line as a separate RUN line.

I had assumed the benefit was to reduce the size of the docker image, but when I tested a large example, either method resulted in the same size.

What is the advantage of chaining commands rather than having individual RUN commands for each line?

Comment: It is explained somewhere in the documentation but I cannot find it now. Each `RUN` command adds a new layer to the image and there is an upper limit of the number of layers allowed (somewhere around 255 or so).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each `RUN` command adds a new layer to the image and there is an upper limit of the number of layers allowed (somewhere around 255 or so). The limitation is enforced for performance reasons.

Every time an application that runs inside the container needs to access a file, the engine searches the file in all these layers, from top to bottom until it finds it. If the application attempts to change a file that is not on the topmost layer then the engine first makes a copy of the file on the topmost layer then handles the application's write requests onto the copy.

The topmost layer is writeable. It is not stored in the image but it is part of the container. The layers stored in the image are read-only.

It is all explained in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/). Keeping a [small number of layers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#minimize-the-number-of-layers) is recommended as [best practice](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/).

Comment: thanks for the explanation.  That very much clarifies things.